# Can a device turn on by itself

Tags: power-on

Can a device turn on by itself without any buttons being pressed? Assume there aren't any custom ROMs

Comment: If it has a feature like that usually called as **Scheduled power** then it can turn on or turn off automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Even stock ROMs have a feature named **Scheduled Power-On**.

Phones have a built-in battery to allow RTC (real time clock) to run while the device is powered off, and it's the base that scheduled power-on is designed.

Here's **Settings -> Advanced -> Scheduled Power On/Off** on my phone (OnePlus 5, Stock 7.1.1)

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I should've clarified, assume that a user has NOT set something like this up